# LiveCharts - DependencyProperty For Fill/Stroke Binding Not Working

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, livecharts

I'm having a problem with a DependencyProperty on a re-usable control I'm creating that plots a single line series using LiveCharts.  The issue is that I have 3 dependency properties I want to configure; one is the Values for the chart, one is fill color of the series, and the last is the stroke color of the line series.  Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataAnalyzer.Controls.QuickPlotSingleLogFile2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataAnalyzer.Controls"
         xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="parentControl">
<Grid x:Name="Grid_Container">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Name="ChartFile" 
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        LegendLocation="None" 
                        DisableAnimations="true" 
                        Hoverable="true" 
                        DataTooltip="{x:Null}" 
                        Margin="10" 
                        BorderBrush="Black">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries x:Name="LineSeries1" 
                            PointGeometry="{x:Null}" 
                            Values="{Binding PlotValues}" 
                            Fill="{Binding FillBrush}" 
                            Stroke="{Binding StrokeBrush}" 
                            AreaLimit="0"></lvc:LineSeries>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Labels=" " Title="Time">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator IsEnabled="False"></lvc:Separator>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
public partial class QuickPlotSingleLogFile2 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Formatter for the datetime in the x-axis for any series
    public Func<double, string> DateTimeSeriesFormatter { get; set; }

    #region PlotValues DP

    public ChartValues<double> PlotValues {
        get { return (ChartValues<double>)GetValue(PlotValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlotValuesProperty, value); }
        }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlotValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PlotValues", typeof(ChartValues<double>), typeof(QuickPlotSingleLogFile2));

    #endregion

    #region FillBrush DP

    public Brush FillBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FillBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(QuickPlotSingleLogFile2), new PropertyMetadata());

    #endregion

    #region StrokeBrush DP

    public Brush StrokeBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(StrokeBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(QuickPlotSingleLogFile2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    public QuickPlotSingleLogFile2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Grid_Container.DataContext = this;

    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

My question is if there is something more I need to do for a property like "Fill"?  The PlotValuesProperty I have configured works exactly as expected -- the binding has no issues.  But I cannot get the binding to work for the fill or stroke brush - it somehow gets lost and livecharts provides default values for fill and stroke.  This user control is used in a parent window and the data context ends up being the window, which is what I want.  I've checked the debugger to ensure that the Data Context is set appropriately, and it seems to work since the Values for the chart are set correctly.  But something odd is happening with the fill/stroke.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to this issue.  I don't understand exactly why, but the reason I wasn't seeing the binding working is because I did not initialize the fill/stroke properties in my main window.

For reference, my original code for the main window (truncated to only show the relevant binding for this custom control) was:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    #region Binding QuickPlotValues
    private ChartValues<double> _quickPlotSingleLogFileValues;
    public ChartValues<double> QuickPlotSingleLogFileValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _quickPlotSingleLogFileValues;
        }
        set
        {
            _quickPlotSingleLogFileValues = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuickPlotSingleLogFileValues");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Binding QuickPlotFill
    private Brush _quickPlotFill;
    public Brush QuickPlotFill
    {
        get
        {
            return _quickPlotFill;
        }
        set
        {
            _quickPlotFill = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuickPlotFill");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Binding QuickPlotStroke
    private Brush _quickPlotStroke;
    public Brush QuickPlotStroke
    {
        get
        {
            return _quickPlotStroke;
        }
        set
        {
            _quickPlotStroke = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuickPlotStroke");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the XAML for the custom control is:

```
<vm:QuickPlotSingleLogFile2 x:Name="PreviewPlotSingleLogFile2"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Margin="20"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            MinHeight="250"
                                            PlotValues="{Binding QuickPlotSingleLogFileValues}"
                                            FillBrush="{Binding QuickPlotFill}"
                                            StrokeBrush="{Binding QuickPlotStroke}"/>
```

I updated my main window code to the following (initializing the fill/stroke colors):

```
 #region Binding QuickPlotFill
    private Brush _quickPlotFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    public Brush QuickPlotFill
    {
        get
        {
            return _quickPlotFill;
        }
        set
        {
            _quickPlotFill = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuickPlotFill");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Binding QuickPlotStroke
    private Brush _quickPlotStroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    public Brush QuickPlotStroke
    {
        get
        {
            return _quickPlotStroke;
        }
        set
        {
            _quickPlotStroke = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuickPlotStroke");
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And suddenly it worked.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but besides the initialization, do you ever set the QuickPlotFill or QuickPlotStroke property? And where exactly are you doing that?

Comment: I do that in my main window.  I actually have a color picker that lets the user assign a color to a specific series, so I pull whatever color that user selected from a stored dictionary.  So once it's been initialized (again I don't understand why I need to do that), I can write the color at any time and it automatically updates behind the scenes and redraws the plot.